# Drools 6.4 OOPath with polymorphic list

Tags: drools

I'm trying to find an elegant OOPath expression to match an Object. My current domain/rule model has

- Events with subtypes, e.g. JobEvent (with a property "jobName"), ServiceEvent
- Alerts, which are caused by one or several events (stored in the Alert object as property "causes" if type List<Event>)

Now I'm trying to write a rule that should trigger and create a new Alert of an JobEvent, if no previous Alert for the same Job exists. I tried

```
rule "Create Alert for Failed Job"
when
   e : JobEvent(status == "FAILURE") from entry-point "JobPoller"
   not ( Alert( /causes{jobName == e.jobName} ) )
```

But quite cleary this results in

```
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: ....Event.jobName()
```

because the type of the list (from the causes property) is Event, and only the subtype JobEvent has the property jobName.

It tried things like

```
not ( Alert( /causes#JobEvent{jobName == e.jobName} ) )
```

or variants of instanceof, but couldn't find a way to express my OOPath query.

Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Why not simply add the method to the base class, throw UnsupportedMethodException there and override (i.e. keep what you have)  in the JobEvent subclass.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, this is more or less what I implemented as a workaround. Flattened out the domain model. This works, and OOPath is nice enough to handle nulls gracefully. Still was wondering if there would be a way to handle this.

Comment: Look at the test here for examples - https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/test/java/org/drools/compiler/xpath/XpathTest.java - The # inline cast goes inside.  Alert( /causes{#JobEvent, jobName == e.jobName}. What this means is the causes list is iterated, where an element matches an instanceof JobEvent it is then applied to the other constraints using that type.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks Mark!